# Add buttons to column in a table generated from data in a database dynamically java swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have the following code for a jtable. it gets data from a database and populates the table. 
Code to get info from db:

```
Vector<Vector<String>> InvoiceDetails = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

Connection conn = dbConnection();
PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("select * from CustomerDetails");

ResultSet rs = pre.executeQuery();

while(rs.next())
{
Vector<String> InvoiceDetail = new Vector<String>();
InvoiceDetail.add(rs.getString(1)); //Empid
InvoiceDetail.add(rs.getString(2)); //name
InvoiceDetail.add(rs.getString(3)); //position
InvoiceDetail.add(rs.getString(4)); 
//need to add code for button here
InvoiceDetails.add(InvoiceDetail);
}
```

jtable code:

```
 public TableExample() throws Exception {

        GetEmployeeDetails dbengine = new GetEmployeeDetails();
        data = dbengine.getEmployee();
         header = new Vector<String>();
        header.add("invoicedata1"); 
        header.add("invoicedata2");
    header.add("invoicedata3"); 
    header.add("invoicedata4"); 
    //need to add button here
    initComponents();


}
```

this is working fine as per now. Now I need to add another column which has buttons which I can click to view some specific data of that column. How can I do this?
Mind that I am new to java. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First of all variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. "InvoiceDetail" should be "invoiceDetail". Most of your names are correct. Be consistent!!!

You can use the [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/).

You simply add a String to your "header" to represent the column name and then add a String to the "invoiceDetails" to represent the text of the button in the column.

The `TableButtonColumn` will provide the renderer and editor for you.